# not able to send data to server using axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs

i am taking the data from form and using submit button i need to send the data to server which is nodejs. but i am not able to send the data to server using axios. and also i am not receiving any error what may be the problem?

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
class Createstudent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert(this.state.value);

  }

  componentDidMount(){
    axios.post('http://localhost:8080/create',{value:this.state.value})
    .then(function(response){
      console.log(response);
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Createstudent;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is proper except the way u r making the post call, 
`componentDidMount` get called only once just after the rendering of the component, so u can't make a post call inside this.

[From React DOCs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount):

> componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is
>   mounted. Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you
>   need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to
>   instantiate the network request.

Write that post call inside `handleSubmit` method, it will work, try this:

```
componentDidMount(){

}

handleSubmit(event) {
    alert(this.state.value);
    axios.post('http://localhost:8080/create',{value:this.state.value})
      .then(function(response){
         console.log(response);
       })
}
```

Comment: ya in my server side its showing only flower brackets

Comment: how can make sure the data from react is sending correctly to server

Comment: goto network in developer mode, when ur application make any request it will come there with url and all the parameters u passed in that, just check the post call string parameters in headers, if it is showing proper parameters then frontend part has no error.

Comment: check this image how to check request and it parameters: http://imgur.com/2pGPHAx

Answer (score 0):

I think `axios.post` should be called from `handleSubmit()`. Currently your code is using axios in `componentDidMount()` which is triggered early(automatically) in the lifecycle of your React component.